# Unresolved attributes reference 'get_videos' class for 'YouTube'

Tags: python, pytube

```
yt = pytube.YouTube(link)
videos = yt.get_videos()
```

I got a warning from the IDE: `unresolved attributes  reference 'get_videos' class for 'YouTube'`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`yt` is a `Youtube` object. According to the documentation a `Youtube` object does not have any method called `get_videos`. Unless you modifies the class `Youtube` by yourself for adding this method, Pycharm (or any other IDE) cannot find the reference to the method as it does not exist.

I think that you should be looking at `Youtube.streams` that returns a `StreamQuery` object from which you can extract `Stream` objects that can be downloaded by first calling the `get_by_itag` method on the `StreamQuery` object followed by the `download` method on the `Stream` object.

The documentation is worth reading in detail, it is not that long and will allow you to understand the object representation of the Youtube videos in this library.
https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#youtube-object